# Python not recognizing list data as a list upon import

Tags: python, import

Extremely simple but frustrating... I'm importing data that is already structured as a list, yet no matter what I try python keeps reading it in as a string.

How do I make ranks[] a proper list instead of a string? It seems like with how this data is formulated this should be near automatic, instead it's fighting me like crazy and making ranks[0] = "["

dataset:

```
['accounting', 5, 9, 11, 0, 0]
['polysci', 1, 2, 24, 0, 0]
```

script:

```
file = open("sub_ranks.txt","r+")
ranks = []
for line in file:
    ranks = line
    group = ranks[0]
    if ranks[1] >= 15:
        print group
        f = open("results.txt","a")
        f.write(group+"\n")
        f.close()
```

Comment: I think you may want file.readlines()

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A better method would be to save your file in a different format, rather than saving in python syntax.  Python gives you many "batteries included" for this - for example, you could use [`json`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html), or write to a [`csv`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) file, or perhaps use [`pickle`](http://docs.python.org/release/3.0.1/library/pickle.html) if the data doesn't need to be human readable.

However, if you're just after a quick and dirty solution then [literal eval](http://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) can give you a list:

```
>>> import ast
>>> s = "['accounting', 5, 9, 11, 0, 0]"
>>> ast.literal_eval(s)
['accounting', 5, 9, 11, 0, 0]
```

Answer (score 3):

Just declaring `ranks=[]` is not going to change all of its futures assignments to a list bject.

You're reading a string from the file, you can use `ast.literal_eval` to convert as string containing a python literal to a python object.

```
from ast import literal_eval

with open("sub_ranks.txt", "r+") as f:

    for line in f:
       ranks = literal_eval(line)
```

---

<sub>- [`file`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#file) is a built-in function in Python2, don't use it as a variable name.</sub>

<sub>-  [It is good practice](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects) to use the `with` keyword when dealing with file objects. This has the advantage that the file is properly closed after its suite finishes, even if an exception is raised on the way.</sub>

Comment: @gravetii We can iterate over a file object in Python, though I should change the variable name `file` to something else.

Comment: @gravetii: no, it shouldn't. That will work, but it pointlessly reads the file into memory before starting the iteration.

Comment: Since files should be accessed with `open`, using file as a variable name is quite fine.  It is even done in the core libraries fairly often.

Answer (score 1):

You are opening file in text mode (default mode). So, all content is read as text. You have two options: parse text data manually or use 'binary' mode and think about serialization logic.

See open() function flags here: http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open